# Animated text funtion only working for certain strings

Tags: python, function, variables

I am attempting to make a function that displays animated text in Python

```
import sys
def anitext(str):
    for char in str:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            time.sleep(textspeed)
    print ("")
```

This function is working for strings such as

```
anitext ("String")
```

And for sole variables such as

```
name = ("Stack")
anitext (name)
```

But will not work for input statements, or conjoined statements like

```
anitext (name, "This is a string")
```

Is there any way for this "Anitext" function to work on statements that are not just plain strings?

*- Olli E*

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use argument unpacking. See [Arbitrary Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) in the official Python tutorial.

```
import sys
import time

textspeed = 0.2

def anitext(*args):
    for s in args:
        for char in s:
            sys.stdout.write(char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(textspeed)
        print("")

anitext("String", "Another string", "More stuff")
```

I've made a couple of other changes to your script. The `sys.stdout.flush()` call ensures that the characters are actually printed one at a time; most terminals will buffer whole lines of text, so you wouldn't actually see the animation happening.

Also, I use `s` for the name of the current string being animated. You should not use `str` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `str` type. That makes your code confusing to read and can also lead to subtle bugs.